# ZigZag Tree printing

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I want to print tree in zigzag order. Here is my code but it is not running. Can Someone point out the mistake ?
I have created two stacks to do the same, my algorithm terminates when two of them are empty, if any of them contains some nodes then these are printed and its childrens are pushed in the other stack. This process continues till both stacks become empty.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

struct TreeNode{
      int value;
      struct TreeNode *left;
      struct TreeNode *right;
};


struct TreeNode stackA[MAX_SIZE]; 
struct TreeNode stackB[MAX_SIZE];

int topA = 0;
int topB = 0;


void push(struct TreeNode stack[], struct TreeNode *node, int *top){
     if(*top > MAX_SIZE){
             printf("stack is full\n");
     }
     else{
          stack[*top] = *node;
          *top = *top +1;
     }
     return;
}

struct TreeNode* pop(struct TreeNode stack[], int *top){
     if(*top == 0){
             printf("stack is empty\n");
               return NULL;
     }
     else{
          struct TreeNode *tmp = stack + *top;
          *top = *top - 1;
          return tmp;
     }


}

int isEmpty(int *top){
        if(*top == 0){
                return 1;
        }

        return 0;
}
void printZigZag(struct TreeNode* root){
     push(stackA,  root,&topA);
     printf("%d\n", topA);
     while(!isEmpty(&topA) || !isEmpty(&topB)){
        while(!isEmpty(&topA)){
           struct TreeNode* temp = pop(stackA,&topA);
           printf("%d", temp->value);
           if(temp->left) push(stackB,temp->left,&topB);
           if(temp->right) push(stackB,temp->right,&topB);
           printf("%d %d",topA,topB);
           return;
       }
       while(!isEmpty(&topB)){
           struct TreeNode *temp = pop(stackB,&topB);
           printf("%d", temp->value);
           if(temp->right) push(stackA,temp->right,&topA);
           if(temp->left) push(stackA,temp->left,&topB);
      }
   }
}


int main(){
    struct TreeNode* root = (struct TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
    root->value = 5;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;

    struct TreeNode* first = (struct TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
    first->value = 15;
    first->left = NULL;
    first->right = NULL;
    root->left = first;


    struct TreeNode* second = (struct TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
    second->value = 235;
    second->left = NULL;
    second->right = NULL;
    root->right = second;


    struct TreeNode *third = (struct TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
    third->value = 45;
    third->left = NULL;
    third->right = NULL;
    first->left = third;


    struct TreeNode *fourth = (struct TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
    fourth->value = 55;
    fourth->left = NULL;
    fourth->right = NULL;
    first->right = fourth;

    printZigZag(root);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One problem is that you don't flush the output you print, which means you won't see any output until the program is done. Either add newlines to the `printf` calls, or explicitly call `fflush` for `stdout`.

Comment: Just for future work, if you wish to see trees as Images, I would recommend you use Graphviz. Make your c program output graphviz code to a file, and use it to get an image. Just an idea that maybe you would be interested in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've check your code. The biggest mistake your have made is that the **Pop** function is implemented by error. The value of ***pop** should be decreased before you get the top value of the stack. Another mistake is that ***if(temp->left) push(stackA,temp->left,&topB)*** should be changed to ***if(temp->left) push(stackA,temp->left,&topA*)**. Below is the code works, I change some small places to fit for c++.

```
#include<cstdio>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

struct TreeNode{
      int value;
      struct TreeNode *left;
      struct TreeNode *right;
};


struct TreeNode stackA[MAX_SIZE]; 
struct TreeNode stackB[MAX_SIZE];

int topA = 0;
int topB = 0;


void push(struct TreeNode stack[], struct TreeNode *node, int *top){
     if(*top > MAX_SIZE){
             printf("stack is full\n");
     }
     else{
          stack[*top] = *node;
          *top = *top +1;
     }
     return;
}

struct TreeNode* pop(struct TreeNode stack[], int *top){
     if(*top == 0){
             printf("stack is empty\n");
               return NULL;
     }
     else{
          *top = *top - 1; 
         struct TreeNode *tmp = stack +*top;         
          return tmp;
     }


}

int isEmpty(int *top){
        if(*top == 0){
                return 1;
        }

        return 0;
}
void printZigZag(struct TreeNode* root){
     push(stackA,  root,&topA);
     while(!isEmpty(&topA) || !isEmpty(&topB)){
        while(!isEmpty(&topA)){
           struct TreeNode* temp = pop(stackA,&topA);
           printf("%d\n", temp->value);
           if(temp->left) push(stackB,temp->left,&topB);
           if(temp->right) push(stackB,temp->right,&topB);
       }
       while(!isEmpty(&topB)){
           struct TreeNode *temp = pop(stackB,&topB);
           printf("%d\n", temp->value);
           if(temp->right) push(stackA,temp->right,&topA);
           if(temp->left) push(stackA,temp->left,&topA);
      }
   }
}

int main(){
    struct TreeNode* root = new TreeNode();
    root->value = 5;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;

    struct TreeNode* first =new TreeNode();
    first->value = 15;
    first->left = NULL;
    first->right = NULL;
    root->left = first;


    struct TreeNode* second = new TreeNode();
    second->value = 235;
    second->left = NULL;
    second->right = NULL;
    root->right = second;


    struct TreeNode *third = new TreeNode();
    third->value = 45;
    third->left = NULL;
    third->right = NULL;
    first->left = third;


    struct TreeNode *fourth = new TreeNode();
    fourth->value = 55;
    fourth->left = NULL;
    fourth->right = NULL;
    first->right = fourth;

    printZigZag(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!